# Draw pixel by pixel in OpenGL ES for iPhone: is it doable, is it inefficient?

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, pixel

I don't have time to frame my question in detail here, but this is my attempt to draw an object pixel-by-pixel. I'm doing this because I wanted to come up with my own 3d to 2d projection methods:

```
#import "PixelatedObject.h"

typedef struct
{
    GLfloat position[2];
    GLubyte color[3];
} Pixel;

@implementation PixelatedObject

static GLKBaseEffect *baseEffect;
static GLKView *baseView;
static GLuint _vertexArrayObject;
static GLuint _pixelBufferObject;
static Pixel *pixels;
static GLuint numPixels;
static GLuint pixelWidth;
static GLuint pixelHeight;

+ (void)setupWithEffect: (GLKBaseEffect *)effect view: (GLKView *)view;
{
    baseEffect = effect;
    baseView = view;

    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArrayObject);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArrayObject);

    pixelWidth = (GLuint) baseView.bounds.size.width;
    pixelHeight = (GLuint) baseView.bounds.size.height;
    numPixels = pixelWidth * pixelHeight;

    pixels = malloc(sizeof(Pixel) * numPixels);
    for (int i = 0; i < pixelWidth; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pixelHeight; j++)
        {
            int index = i * pixelHeight + j;
            pixels[index].position[0] = i;
            pixels[index].position[1] = j;
            pixels[index].color[0] = (GLubyte) arc4random() % 256;
            pixels[index].color[1] = (GLubyte) arc4random() % 256;
            pixels[index].color[2] = (GLubyte) arc4random() % 256;
        }
    }

    glGenBuffers(1, &_pixelBufferObject);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _pixelBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Pixel) * numPixels, pixels, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Pixel), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Pixel, position));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Pixel), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Pixel, color));


    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

- (void)debug
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++)
    {
        Pixel pixel = pixels[i];
        NSLog(@"Pixel %i: {%6.1f,%6.1f} {%-3i,%-3i,%-3i}",
              i,
              pixel.position[0], pixel.position[1],
              pixel.color[0], pixel.color[1], pixel.color[2]);
    }
}

- (void)render
{
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArrayObject);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _pixelBufferObject);
    [baseEffect prepareToDraw];
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, numPixels);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
}

@end
```

Then I just render it in my ViewController, but nothing is popping up. Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: Why are you feeding in each pixel as a vertex? Why not a texture? Why not use a shader running over a quad for per-pixel rendering?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @BradLarson. I'm sorry, but I honestly have no idea what that means. Could you please provide an example because the internet is really dry when it comes to per pixel rendering for iOS with GLKit and OpenGL ES.

Comment: @BradLarson I have created my best naive attempt at doing what you said, and now maybe you can point me in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448212/how-to-draw-to-pixels-of-a-texture-in-opengl-es-glkit

Comment: If you want an example of how to run per-pixel operations using shaders, I built an entire framework for that: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage . While intended for image processing, you can ignore the input image and do your per-pixel calculations in a shader to generate an arbitrary output. You can take a look at the various shaders and how they operate in there, and it can handle the OpenGL ES setup for you.